# Unable to acesse QWidget in UI file, PySide

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

```
AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QWidget' object has no attribute 'test_button'
```

I get this error when run the following code
test.py.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtUiTools
module_dir = os.path.dirname('__file__')
ui_file_path = module_dir + '/test.ui'
def call_ui():
    loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
    ui_file = QtCore.QFile(ui_file_path)
    ui_file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
    ui = loader.load(ui_file)
    ui_file.close()
    return ui
class TestUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = call_ui()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui)
        self.ui.test_button.clicked.connected(self.test)
    def test(self):
        print "Testing....."
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TestUI()
    win.show()
main()
```

test.ui file has a push button called test_button

Answer (score 0):

You can't construct path of UI file in this way:

```
os.path.dirname('__file__')
```

will always return empty string, and *ui_file_path* will be *'/test.ui'*.

Correct way:

```
module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ui_file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'test.ui')
```

But when QUiLoader.load failed, it raises RuntimeError (tested on PySide 1.2.1). Is there a ui file on your root file system?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i don't think that is the issue when i remove     "self.ui.test_button.clicked.connected(self.test)" it works fine. When ever i try to connect or modify any widget from my code this error pops up.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem due to lacking of full traceback and the code which you **actually** run (there are too many typos)